# Writing a Book and Large Projects in Latex

Tags: texstudio, overleaf, books, vscode

I am a physics student and also an avid LaTex user. I'm currently making a book containing my notes in overleaf. I'm planning to do this long term, so I'm planning to type hundreds of pages. However, I'm not sure if this is a good idea as I considered overleaf's timeouts.

Is an offline editor such as TexStudio, VSCode, etc better for large projects like this?

Comment: for such a long term project I'd want to use a source control such as git which means for overleaf you'd probably want the paid-for version (which also has bigger time limits) or (what I would actually do, is use a local tex installation) but really this isn't clearly on topic as you are just asking for a review of a commercial system

Comment: Besides version control and online access you may want to have a look at package https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfiles , which allows you to compile sub-files, like subsections, or the whole book, e.g. while you are working on a set of new information.

Comment: For larger projects, I would really not use the free Overleaf version, but rather install TeX locally. But, of course, it depends on your workflow. If you work from different devices often, a cloud-based solution such as Overleaf might be better ... In the end, I feel that this is a question which only you can answer for yourself.

Comment: Well, and if you have access to a free or low-cost webserver, you can install a Latex environment, git, Redmine etc. and log-in from anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, @MS-SPO. I'm already aware and using the subfiles package. However, it doesn't seem to help much in overleaf as my 60-pages project is nearing the timeout for  free plans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Jasper, I would also prefer local installations, but I would also consider the cloud. For a 400-page project, I had to work on several different computers (and OS's). A cloud with the same data on all systems was practical. Then came working with the same editor on all systems. Plus the literature management (also in the cloud as a .bib). This meant I could work with the same data anytime and anywhere and didn't have to worry about having to interrupt my work.